# Anybody tried scala with stripes framework

Tags: java, scala, netbeans

Is it possible to integrate stripes and scala such that controllers are written in scala and views in JSP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it is. Scala compiles to JVM bytecodes. As long as you keep interfaces to what the framework expects every thing works fine.